# Part of my Python Code is not functioning, but all other parts are

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code in Python that I recently created for a Maths Assignment, but part of it is not working.

So it asks the user to select a choice, but when I tested it, all other options (which I took out) worked for me, but when I entered "4", it wouldn't work. Instead, it just reprinted everything and asked for my choice again.

FYI: I have taken out the other options, because they aren't needed here.

Does anybody have a solution though? Because whatever I do, it doesn't seem to function or work.

Here's the part of my code that has the problem:

```
#This part greets the user, and lets the user know that the application has started
print("Hello there!")
#This starts off the loop, but this variable may be changed later on
cont = "yes"
#This is the actual loop
while cont == "yes" or cont == "Yes" or cont == "YES":
  print("Choose an option below:")
#This shows the options
  print("1) Calculate the value of different product sizes")
  print("2) Calculate the sale price")
  print("3) Calculate the discount")
  print("4) Create a shopping list")
  print("5) Create a receipt that shows costs")
  print("6) Exit")
#This part lets the user choose what they would like to do
  option = float(input("Choose an option (1/2/3/4/5/6): "))
#This is what happens if the user chooses Option 4
#This is the "Shopping list" part of the application below
  if option == 4:
    sl = []
    import os,sys,time
    try:
      f = open("Shopping_List.txt","r")
      for line in f:
        sl.append(line.strip())
      f.close
    except:
      pass
    def mainScreen():
      os.system("cls")
      print("Just a couple reminders:")
      print("Your shopping list contains", len(sl), "items so far.")
      print("If items aren't deleted from the list after use, they'll remain there.")
      print("Choose an option below:")
      print("1) Add an item to the list")
      print("2) Delete an item from the list")
      print("3) View the list")
      print("4) Exit")
      asdf = input("Enter your choice here: ")
      if len(asdf) > 0:
        if choice.lower()[0] == "1":
          addScreen
        elif choice.lower()[0] == "2":
          deleteScreen()
        elif choice.lower()[0] == "3":
          viewScreen()
        elif choice.lower()[0] == "4":
          sys.exit()
        else:
          mainScreen()
      else: mainScreen()
    def addScreen():
      global sl
      os.system('cls')
      print("Press ENTER if you would like to exit.")
      print("Enter the name of the item you would like to add below.")
      item = input("Name of item: ")
      if len(item) > 0:
        sl.append(item)
        print("Item has been added.")
        saveList()
        time.sleep(1)
        addScreen()
      else:
        mainScreen
    def viewScreen():
      os.system('cls')
      for item in sl:
        print(item)
      print("Press ENTER to exit.")
      input()
      mainScreen()
    def deleteScreen():
      global sl
      os.system('cls')
      count = 0
      for item in sl:
        print(count, ") - ", item)
        count = count + 1
      print("Enter the number corresponding to the item you would like to delete.")
      chce = ("Number: ")
      if len(chce) > 0:
        try:
          del sl[int(chce)]
          print("Item has been deleted.")
          saveList()
          time.sleep(1)
        except:
          print("Invalid number.")
          time.sleep(1)
        deleteScreen()
      else:
        mainScreen()
    def saveList():
      f = open("Shopping_List.txt", "w")
      for item in sl:
        f.write(item + "\n")
      f.close()
    mainScreen
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't find option 4 in this. Please reduce it to a [mcve]

Comment: your code is just too long and has too many `if-else` statements, can you focus and extract your issue?

Comment: Explain "not working". Show expected and real output or error messages as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You should convert the input to `int`, not `float`. The line `mainScreen` at the bottom does nothing - it should be `mainScreen()`.  And `cont == "yes" or cont == "Yes" or cont == "YES"`  could be just `cont.lower() == "yes"`.

Comment: ```if choice.lower()[0] == "1":
          addScreen``` should be
```if choice.lower()[0] == "1":
          addScreen()```

Comment: Might be better if you create an answer with your example source and how your understanding has changed. Especially the difference between a function_name ... a reference and a function_name() ... calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

The line at the bottom of my code should be changed from `mainScreen` to `mainScreen()`, otherwise it wouldn't do anything. And also, `if choice.lower()[0] == "1": addScreen` should be `if choice.lower()[0] == "1": addScreen()`, or otherwise, that part of my code wouldn't function either, which would create further problems.

*Credit goes to Keith John Hutchison and MaxiMouse for helping me figure out how to solve my problem, why it didn't work, and for also suggesting improvements to my code.*